# Why are the contents of my batch file being interpreted as alt codes?

Tags: batch-file, adb

I'm using a batch file to execute some adb commands. When trying to do a longpress of the power key I use the following line:

`adb -s <ipaddress>:5555 shell input keyevent --longpress 26`.

If I type this command into cmd, it works without a hitch. Running it from the batch file, however, results in a short press. I created a single line batch file, with the above command as the sole contents. When running the batch file (I just type the file name in cmd), the command is printed as:

`adb -s <ipaddress>:5555 shell input keyevent -ΓÇôlongpress 26`

Is there a setting I may have unknowingly enabled that is causing this, or do I need some sort of escape character?

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather embarrassed that I came across a solution to my issue only a few minutes after posting this, but I figure I should share and not waste anyone's time.

I've replaced the second hyphen in my command with its own alt code (i.e. alt 45) and it is now interpreted correctly in the batch file. The line still reads:

`adb -s <ipaddress>:5555 shell input keyevent --longpress 26`

I don't understand why this works, and would appreciate it if someone would shed light on the subject.

**Edit:** Based off the recommendation of the comment below, I looked up the differences between encoding schemes. If I understand it correctly, when encoding in ASCII or ANSI, characters are limited to 7 bits of data. This will keep characters in the first 128 members of the ASCII table, so the alt codes I saw previously couldn't be generated.

Comment: What encoding did you use to save the batch file? is it ASCII/ANSI? well, it should...

Comment: According to the encoding tab of Notepad++, UTF-8.